# Store the sorted order after sorting a object in java

Tags: java, collections

Lets take a simple example . Here is a class

```
public class Student
{int classRank;
 String Name
 float marks
}
```

to this class lets say there are 5 objects s1,s2,s3,s4,s5 and I use comparator to sort the objects in a order. My question is can I somehow store the classRank at same time the comparator is running. If not is there a better way than doing this

```
int rank = 0;
for(Student s: students)
{ s.setClassRank(++rank);
}
```

Comment: Try and be clearer. Do you mean Store to a Variable or to File?

Comment: But you already have the `classRank` because it's part of the object itself...did I misunderstood your question?

Comment: I don't recommend doing it. It will be better to first sort the list, then update the state of the objects in it. Imagine if an object is swapped twice or more inside the list, how will you handle that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot store the rank at the same time that the comparator is running, because, well, there is nothing to store: until the comparator is finished, the ranks are not final. Besides, it is not a good idea to modify your objects when the sort is running.

If you must store the rank, use your code, or apply a similar-looking `for` loop, and use loop variable to set the rank. However, it is probably a poor design, because as soon as you add some students to the back of the list, the ranks are going to change. A better design would keep student objects separately, and sort a different object connected to the student and to the list inside which the student is ranked. This would let you keep multiple rank lists for the same group of students.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot do it *while* sorting, because the sorting method works in mysterious fashion. ;-)

If `students` is a list, you can use old-style `for` loop to save extra counter.

```
for (int i = 0; i < students.size(); i++)
    students.get(i).setClassRank(i + 1);
```